# Problems mounting a Vercel/Nextjs project as a subdirectory of a different Vercel/Nextjs project

Tags: next.js, url-rewriting, vercel

I have a monorepo with two projects - `web` and `docs`. Each of these is their own Vercel project with the `web` project mounted at https://example.com and `docs` mounted at https://docs.example.com.  All of this works as expected.

I now want to have the `docs` project be available at https://example.com/docs.  In the `web` project, I setup the following rewrites in my `vercel.json` file.

```json
{
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "/docs/:match*",
      "destination": "https://docs.example.com/:match*"
    },
    { "source": "/(.*)", "destination": "/" }
  ]
}
```

This works for the main index file, but all of the corresponding css and js files result in 404's. The browser is looking for those files at https://example.com/_next which isn't correct, it should be looking at https://docs.example.com/_next.

How do I make this work?

Comment: Have you looked into setting up a [`basePath`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/basepath) in the docs app?

Comment: I can't set both the `web` and `docs` projects to `example.com`. If I use the basePath in the `docs` app, the `docs` app would just be rooted at `docs.example.com/docs` which isn't what I want.

Comment: It's bad practice to have the same content at two locations. Choose docs.example.com or example.com/docs as the right location. Set the right basePath for this location. Then use redirect instead of rewrite from the other location to this one.

Comment: @some-user Yes, that's what I actually want. I can't figure out how to get this to work. I can't set both projects to be hosted at example.com so I set one up to docs.example.com thinking I could redirect it. Can you be more explicit as to what domain each project should use and what the rewrites should be?

Answer (score 5):

### `rewrite` vs. `redirect`

Let's first understand this difference.

A [rewrite](https://vercel.com/docs/project-configuration#project-configuration/rewrites) is something that happens on the server only. The server will rewrite the URL that has been requested and search for content of that rewritten URL. The client will not know anything about that. E.g. if /a.html is rewritten to /b.html, the client will receive the same content on both URLs. Client won't know, if there is the same file two times or if one (or both) requests have been rewritten to some other resource.

A [redirect](https://vercel.com/docs/project-configuration#project-configuration/redirects) on the other hand side involves the client (i.e. browser). If the server is asked for an URL that should be redirected, it will reply back to the client/browser with the destination URL of the rewrite. The client will then send another request for the new URL and make this visible to the end user by changing the address in the navigation bar. If /a.html is redirected to /b.html, the client will not receive the actual content of b.html when requesting a.html, but the browser will update the address to b.html and send a new request.

### What's the issue with rewrites in your case?

The HTML contains references to other resources using absolute paths, e.g. something like:

```html
<script src="/_next/static/..."></script>
```

If this file should be served as `docs.example.com` and `example.com/docs` (e.g. using rewrites), the actual HTML will not change. The browser will thus try to access `docs.example.com/_next/static/...` or `example.com/_next/static/...` respectively. That works for the first case (`docs.example.com`), but not for the second one. You've noticed that already.

You can change the [`basePath`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/basepath) of next, e.g. to `/docs`. Then the HTML would contain `<script src="/docs/_next/...">`. That would make the browser request `docs.example.com/docs/_next/...` or `example.com/docs/_next/...` respectively. That would work for the second case, but not the first one. You could heal the first case with more rewrite rules, but I'd suggest a KISS solution.

### Now what?

As mentioned in the comments, placing the exact same content at two different addresses is not good practice. And you can see, that is is causing subsequent difficulties as well. (Not to mention punishment by search engines for duplicate content.)

A good solution would be to decide where to store the content. That should be either `docs.example.com` or `example.com/docs`, not both.

#### Using docs.example.com, forwarding example.com/docs/ to docs.example.com

I'd suggest (and assume in this section) to take `docs.example.com` to have a clear separation of concerns.

So in Vercel you would set up two projects. One for your "main" next instance, another one for the "docs" next instance. (Both can come from the same repo, that doesn't matter.)

You then assign domains to both projects, e.g. `www.example.com` to the "main" project, `docs.example.com` to the "docs" project.
`example.com` as well as `docs.example.com` should be working right now.
`example.com/docs/` should yield a 404 error.

Then you add redirects (not rewrites!) for your "main" project by adding a `vercel.json` like this:

```json
{
  "redirects": [
    { "source": "/docs/:path*", "destination": "https://docs.example.com/:path*" }
  ]
}
```

Now, if you enter `example.com/docs/foo` in your browser, you should be redirected to `docs.example.com/foo` and the page should load properly.

#### Using only example.com/docs/

If you decide to have the docs content only at `example.com/docs/`, the solution would be as follows:

- Add `basePath: '/docs'` to `next.config.js` of the docs next project. Do not add a domain to this vercel project.
- In the "main" next project add a `vercel.json` with a rewrite like this:

```json
{
  "rewrites": [
    { "source": "/docs", "destination": "https://$domain-of-docs-project.vercel.app/docs" },
    { "source": "/docs/:path*", "destination": "https://$domain-of-docs-project.vercel.app/docs/:path*" }
  ]
}
```

Please comment, if you have additional questions or this doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: Cool, that redirect works. How would I do it if I only want the content at `example.com/docs`?

Comment: I extended the solution above to cover this case.

Comment: Thanks. I added the base path to the `docs` project and removed the domain (only the `example-docs.vercel.app` remains. I then added the rewrites to the `vercel.json` file of the `main` project. Now when I go to `example.com/docs` I get **This page isn't working. Too many rewrites.**.

Comment: If I remove the basepath from the `docs` project and point the destination of the rewrite to `https://example-docs.vercel.app/:path*` then the rewrite works but it is looking for the css and other assets in `https://example.com/_next/static/css` instead of at `https://example-docs.vercel.app/_next_static/css`.

Comment: I've added another rewrite rule might solve the redirect issue even though I cannot reproduce it. Please check your vercel/next config for additional redirects that should not be there.

Comment: Really appreciate the help. This now works for everything but things in the `/public` folder in the docs project. Images and font files are returning 404's but everything else works. It's looking for them at https://example.com/docs/_next/image?url=%2Flogo-dark.png&w=640&q=75. Found this https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/17889 but looks like it should have been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the **vercel.json** like this:

```js
{
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "/:path*",
      "has": [
        {
          "type": "host",
          "value": "docs.example.com"
        }
      ],
      "destination": "/docs/:path*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. I end up with a 404 when I hit `example.com/docs`.

Answer (score 0):

Next offers a specific example for this.

Your "web" project should handle rewrites, as seen [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-zones/home/next.config.js).
next.config.js:

```
const { DOCS_URL } = process.env //this should be the vercel URL NOT docs.example.com

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
module.exports = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/:path*',
        destination: `/:path*`,
      },
      {
        source: '/docs',
        destination: `${DOCS_URL}/docs`,
      },
      {
        source: '/blog/:path*',
        destination: `${BLOG_URL}/docs/:path*`,
      },
    ]
  },
}
```

Your "docs" app needs to set a base path, as seen [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-zones/blog/next.config.js). next.config.js:

```
    module.exports = {
      basePath: '/docs',
    }
```

Then to ensure that docs.example.com no longer serves the docs as well, I'd just remove the DNS record. Instead you'll just have a vercel URL that you will use in the rewrites in "web". No need to point to that server from docs.example.com.

[Nextjs documentation for multi-zone](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/multi-zones)

[Nextjs example with multi-zones](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-zones)

Comment: This works for everything but the `/public` folder in the `docs` project. Images and fonts all return 404s. It's looking for them at https://example.com/docs/_next/image?url=%2Flogo-dark.png&w=640&q=75.  Any thoughts on how to fix that?

Comment: Are these fonts and images coming from the docs app, or the main app? 

Seems that "baseUrl" may not effect public. try this, add: `{ source: '/docs/_next/:path*', destination: '${BLOG_URL}/_next/:path}` to your next.config.js